# Siffler à / dans ses oreilles

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour,

Est-ce qu'il y a une différence entre ces deux phrases ?

> Le vent siffle à ses oreilles.
>
> Le vent siffle dans ses oreilles.

Est-ce que la première est plus courante ?

Answer (score 3):

En plus du sens propre toujours possible, ***siffler aux oreilles*** (*siffler à ses oreilles*) est une expression idiomatique en français. Elle se réfère à l'expression ***avoir les oreilles qui sifflent*** qui signifie au sens figuré que d'autres personnes situées ailleurs sont en train de parler de soi, en général sous forme de médisance.

***Siffler dans les oreilles*** est une expression qui est elle le plus souvent utilisée au sens propre et qui signifie simplement que quelque chose produit un sifflement assez fort et proche perçu par les oreilles de quelqu'un.

Dans le cas de la question, il ne peut s'agir que du sens propre et les deux sont techniquement possibles mais je recommanderais la première forme, ***le vent siffle à ses oreilles*** qui est plus élégante.

Answer (score 2):

En ce qui concerne l'utilisation de « siffler à ses oreilles » et « siffler dans ses oreilles » spécialisées au vent il n'y a de nos jours pratiquement aucune différence, les deux constructions sont presque aussi fréquentes l'une que l'autre. ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vent+siffler+%C3%A0+ses+oreilles%2Cvent+siffler+dans+ses+oreilles&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvent%20siffler%20%C3%A0%20ses%20oreilles%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvent%20siffler%20dans%20ses%20oreilles%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cvent%20siffler%20%C3%A0%20ses%20oreilles%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvent%20siffler%20dans%20ses%20oreilles%3B%2Cc0)). Pour ce qui est de l'utilisation de ces expressions en général on constate que celle avec « à » est de loin la plus courante, et elle l'a été de tous temps. ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=siffler+%C3%A0+ses+oreilles%2Csiffler+dans+ses+oreilles&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csiffler%20%C3%A0%20ses%20oreilles%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csiffler%20dans%20ses%20oreilles%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csiffler%20%C3%A0%20ses%20oreilles%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csiffler%20dans%20ses%20oreilles%3B%2Cc0))

[image]

[image]

Néanmoins, dans le cas particulier où le verbe est conjugué à la 3ième personne du singulier il n'y a pas de trace de l'expression construite ave « dans ». ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vent+siffle+%C3%A0+ses+oreilles%2Cvent+siffle+dans+ses+oreilles&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvent%20siffle%20%C3%A0%20ses%20oreilles%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cvent%20siffle%20%C3%A0%20ses%20oreilles%3B%2Cc0))

[image]

Si on remplace « siffle » par « sifflait » l'expression avec « à » est beaucoup plus courante ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vent+sifflait+%C3%A0+ses+oreilles%2Cvent+sifflait+dans+ses+oreilles&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvent%20sifflait%20%C3%A0%20ses%20oreilles%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvent%20sifflait%20dans%20ses%20oreilles%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cvent%20sifflait%20%C3%A0%20ses%20oreilles%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvent%20sifflait%20dans%20ses%20oreilles%3B%2Cc0)).

[image]

On peut donc penser que « à » convient mieux.